# Switching arrays to left in PHP

Tags: php

I have a simple array like:

```
array(0 => '', 1 => '2014-03-28 08:17:11', 2 => '2014-03-28 08:26:11', 
      3 => '2014-03-28 08:32:05', 4 => '2014-03-28 08:49:00', 
      5 => '2014-03-28 09:24:24')
```

and I'd like to switch that array to have empty index at last position and filled with same date of previous index but at 23:59:59

Is there maybe a function that could do that switch ?

Comment: start from here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php

Comment: No common PHP function will do that. As @LorenzoMarcon says, first get rid of the 0, then parse the last index to get the date, and `push` the new date.

Comment: How did you arrive at _23:59:59_ or is it always standard ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all your responses but at the end I followed this method:

```
$date = new DateTime($intervaldates[sizeof($intervaldates)-1]);
$intervaldates[0] = $date->setTime(23, 59, 59)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$dates = array_map('strtotime', $intervaldates);
sort($dates);
```

so in this way I can be sure to obtain last date interval setting the time to 23:59:59...

Answer (score 0):

Filter the empty elements using `array_filter` and then grab an element from an array, `explode` it by space and then take the first element and append it to your max time.

```
<?php
$dt=array(0 => '', 1 => '2014-03-28 08:17:11', 2 => '2014-03-28 08:26:11',3 => '2014-03-28 08:32:05', 4 => '2014-03-28 08:49:00', 5 => '2014-03-28 09:24:24');
$dt=array_filter($dt);
array_push($dt,$v=explode(' ',$dt[1])[0].' 23:59:59');
print_r($dt);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2014-03-28 08:17:11
    [2] => 2014-03-28 08:26:11
    [3] => 2014-03-28 08:32:05
    [4] => 2014-03-28 08:49:00
    [5] => 2014-03-28 09:24:24
    [6] => 2014-03-28 23:59:59
)
```